# Make Array in Jquery For AJAX Posting

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery

```
$('#saveplaylist').click(function () { 
                var length = $(' .organizer-media').length;
                var contents=$(' .organizer-media');
                var data = null;
                for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                    data[i] = contents[i].title;
                }
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: JSON.stringify(data),
                    url: '/Builder/Save',
                    success: function () {
                        alert("Playlist saved successfully!!");
                    }
                })
            })
```

As shown above in my code I am not able to send my values by making an array of data filled by using for loop How can I make an array of data & post it through AJAX?

Comment: Why did not declare data as array variable ? Use array push method instead of manually added data into array index.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to initialize the variable as an array, not `null`.

```
var data = [];
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what Barmar said, you need to set content type of your ajax call to JSON

```
$.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: JSON.stringify(data),
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    url: '/Builder/Save',
                    success: function () {
                        alert("Playlist saved successfully!!");
                    }
                })
```

Comment: why this Contenttype is necessary. Without this the code is working.

Answer (score 1):

Remove space from `' .organizer-media'` and `' .organizer-media'`

and change

```
var data = null;
```

to

```
var data = new Array();
```

Comment: this spacing in ' .organizer-media' doesn't affects the code execution then why I should do the changes?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of JSON.stringify() you could use the [$.param() method](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/)

```
$('#saveplaylist').click(function () { 
    var length = $(' .organizer-media').length;
    var contents=$(' .organizer-media');
    var data = null;
    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        data[i] = contents[i].title;
    }
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        data: $.param({data: data}),
        url: '/Builder/Save',
        success: function () {
            alert("Playlist saved successfully!!");
        }
    });
});
```

This will store the content titles as members of the data array, which you should be able to access server side.

In Rails you would access this like so:

```
titles = params[:data]
```

In PHP it might be something like:

```
$titles = $_POST["data"];
```

**EDIT:**

One thing I missed, as Barmar mentioned above, you need to initialize data as an empty array, not null.